# How to Recover Lost Media Files (Photos, Music, etc) from iPhone 6 Device

Tags: data-recovery, recovery, iphone

Do you know how to recover media files from iPhone 6? I lost my photos and music by some accident.

Comment: For starters, what was the accident? How did you lose your photos and music?

Comment: From your last backup - iCloud or iTunes.